# ZombieJS: intermittently crashes when called repeatedly from a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, assert, zombie.js

I have a ZombieJS node server on Heroku scrapping data from the internet. The server code is called from a `for` loop on the client side. Each iteration of the loop makes a server call which makes a Zombie scrape. Sometimes, the server will crash with the error below. It only happens when there is more than one iteration of the `for` loop.

How can I make the code robust enough to handle multiple simultaneous client calls, each with a `for` loop.

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var Browser = require('zombie');    // tried changing var to const; no difference
var assert = require('assert');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

var printMessage = function() { console.log("Node app running on " + app.get('port')); };

var getAbc = function(response, input)
{
    var browser = new Browser(); 
    browser.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0'; 
    browser.runScripts = true;
    var url = "http://www.google.com/ncr"; 

    browser.visit(url, function() {
        browser.fill('q', input).pressButton('Google Search', function(){
            // parsing number of results from browser object

            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            response.end(numberOfSearchResults); 
        });
    });
}

var handleXyz = function(request, response)
{
    getAbc(response, request.query.input); 
}

app.listen(app.get('port'), printMessage); 
app.post('/xyz', handleXyz);
```

Error:

```
 assert.js:86
   throw new assert.AssertionError({
              ^
 No open window with an HTML document
     at Browser.field (/app/node_modules/zombie/lib/index.js:811:7)
     at Browser.fill (/app/node_modules/zombie/lib/index.js:903:24)
     at /app/cfv1.js:42:11
     at done (/app/node_modules/zombie/lib/eventloop.js:589:9)
     at timeout (/app/node_modules/zombie/lib/eventloop.js:594:33)
     at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:119:15)
```

I have a similar project using HorsemanJS/PhantomJS which fails in a similar way (I'm stuck on that too!): [NodeJS server can't handle multiple users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306822/nodejs-server-cant-handle-multiple-users)

Comment: I ran a quick test and it seems to work okay. Can you add browser.debug() and see if you can get more information from your logs?

Comment: Did you repeatedly call it from a `for` loop? It only fails sometimes.

Comment: Where would I put `browser.debug()`?

Comment: I would just put it after you instantiate the browser (i.e. - var browser = new Browser(); browser.debug();

Comment: I was able to reproduce. I was actually testing loading one of my own sites instead of Google (for various reasons), but actually using Google causes the error. I'm guessing Google is returning a different response b/c you're sending too many requests within a short period of time. I can take a closer look at the exact issue later today.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think you should be careful or just avoid generating a lot of unsolicited requests to remote servers. Many sites will throttle you and/or start rejecting connections. With that said, I believe I found the source of the issue in this particular case.

I tested the code snippet and for this particular case, Google will reset the connection if you make too many requests. When the connection is reset, one of the variables ends up failing an assertion.

The error I get when the connection is reset:

```
  zombie TypeError: read ECONNRESET
    at zombie/lib/pipeline.js:89:15
    at tryCatcher (zombie/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (zombie/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:497:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (zombie/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:555:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (zombie/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:600:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (zombie/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:679:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (zombie/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:125:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (zombie/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:135:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (zombie/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:16:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

I get your original error further down, but the source of the problem is actually because of the above. When the above happens, it causes document.documentElement to be a false-y value and subsequently causes this assertion in zombie/lib/index.js in the field function to fail:

```
assert(this.document && this.document.documentElement, 'No open window with an HTML document');
```

I think the easiest solution is to handle the error on the client end and try to recover gracefully.

Comment: This is great; thank you very much.

Any recommendation on how to handle the error gracefully?

Comment: It depends on the UX desired for your application. I assume that you can detect when the response is an error. You can either display that there was an error and ask the user to retry or retry automatically. If you retry automatically, you'll probably want something like exponential back off since the server is essentially overloaded. Ideally, you'd catch the error on the server so that it doesn't crash, but I think you need to modify Zombie to throw an exception instead of an AssertionError (I don't know if there's a way to recover from a failed assert). I imagine that would be more work.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are making a new instance of the Browser object for each call. My guess is the previous "Browser" is still closing, or hasn't been handled by the garbage collector when the next call is trying to open another. Try moving the instantiation of the Browser to outside of getAbc()

Comment: I tried moving `var browser = new Browser()` just below the `require` block but it didn't help.